# What symmetry property in complex space is related to |a+ib| = |b+ia|?

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers, symmetry

What symmetry property in complex space is related to the fact that the absolute value of numbers $|a+ib| = |b+ia|$ are equals?

Comment: what's symmetry property exactly?

Comment: That circles are symmetric?????

Comment: that's the question. We know for sure the absolute value of number $z_1  = a + ib$ and $z_2  = b + ia$ is $|z_1| = |z_2 = sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. this is a reflection over line $w = x+ ix$. But why complex space satisfy this symmetry?

Comment: if modules are equal geometrically both numbers lie on a circle, if you change a and b on places they are symmetrical  to line re{C}=im{C}.

Comment: But is there a reason for all  points on complex numbers being symmetrical to line line re{C}=im{C}?

Comment: for every point we can find symmetrical,  ..  in cartesian geometry:vector (a-b, b-a) is orthogonal to the (1,1) because dot product is equal 0.

Comment: so your points lie on the circle and vector connecting points is perpendicular to the (1,1) which is on the line through (0,0), so it must be a symmetry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading the comment of fleablood and  Widawensen about the numbers laid of a circle, I think that the correct answer is:

The wanted property is that the absolute value of a number must be invariant under any axis rotation. In this case all numbers $z_1 = a + ib$, $z_2 = -a + ib$, $z_3 = a - ib$, $z_4 = -a - ib$, $z_5 = b + ia$, $z_6 = -b + ia$, $z_7 = b - ia$ and $z_8 = -b - ia$ and other infinity have the same absolute value.

Comment: The isotropy of complex space!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you identify the complex space $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ by sending $z = a + ib$ to $(a,b)$, the norm of a complex number $z$ is the same as (regular, Euclidean) the norm of the vector $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the following two maps:

1. The conjugation map $T \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $T(a + ib) = T(z) = \overline{z} = a - ib$.
2. The multiplication by $-i$ map $S \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $S(z) = S(a + ib) = (-i)z = (-i)(a + ib) = b - ia$.

The map $T$ is not a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map but under the identification of $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$, it corresponds to an $\mathbb{R}$-linear reflection map across the $x$-axis which preserves the norms of vectors. The map $S$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map that corresponds under the identification of $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a rotation map by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ degrees clockwise which also preserves norms of vectors.

Hence, the composition $T \circ S$ also preserves the norms of vectors and

$$ (T \circ S)(a + ib) = T(b - ia) = b + ia $$

which implies that $|a + ib| = |b + ia|$ (which of course can be verified directly using the definition of the norm).

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb R^2$, the map $(a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$ is reflection in the
45-degree line $y=x$.  This map is (of course) an isometry of the plane, so it is an isometry of $\mathbb C$.